# How to add placeholder text with search icon on jQuery data tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I'm using jQuery data tables and I want to display "search" text with search icon inside search input box as placeholder. I managed add the text. Please advice me how to add placeholder image

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            oLanguage: {
                sSearch: ''
            },
            "aoColumnDefs":[{
                'bSortable':false, 'aTargets':[3]

            }
            ]
        });

        function InitComplete(oSettings) {
            $('#example_filter')
                    .contents()
                    .filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3 })
                    .replaceWith('Refine search: ');
        }

        $('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "Search");
```

I need to know, how to add image something like `'<i class='icon-search'></i>'`

Comment: use 'cover' block above the `input`, for `placeholder` immitation. This will give you more control - like here https://gyazo.com/d94e99df0a576fe4b55e89b340bc242f

Comment: Have you try my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For make that, you can use `background-image`. try

**UPDATE**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    $(".searchIn").keypress(function(){
      $(this).removeClass().addClass("searchOut")
    })
    
    $(".searchIn").click(function(){
      if(!$(this).hasClass("searchOut"))
        $(this).addClass("searchIn")
    })
    
    $(document).on("keyup",".searchOut", function(){
      if(($(this).val().length) == 0 )
        $(this).removeClass().addClass("searchIn")
    })
})
```

```css
.searchIn{
  background:url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-website/512/search-website-512.png) no-repeat scroll left center / 15px auto;
}

.searchOut{
background:none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <input type="text" class="searchIn"  />
</div>
```

Comment: i want to make the image as placeholder

Answer (score 18):

Add

```
"searchPlaceholder": "search"
```

Ex

```
$('#datatable').DataTable({
        "dom": 'lCfrtip',
            "order": [],
            "colVis": {
            "buttonText": "Hiển thị",
                "overlayFade": 0,
                "align": "right"
        },
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": '_MENU_ bản ghi trên trang',
                "search": '<i class="fa fa-search"></i>',
                "searchPlaceholder": "search",
                "paginate": {
                "previous": '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
                    "next": '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .css() in jquery:

```
$(".dataTables_filter input").css("background-image", "url('yourImageURL')");
```

but as you mentioned that you want to use an icon, you can use an input field with an `<i>` tag. using CSS you can set the position of the icon in a place that the user would think it's on the `<input>` tag:

the HTML could look like this :

```
<input type="text" id="username">
<i class='icon-search'></i>
```

then you have to give the icon-search a position where it can be seen inside of the input depending on where the `<input>` tag is positioned. sth like this:

```
.icon-search {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 36px;
    width: 36px;    
    text-align: center;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code to add a placeholder text for the search in jQuery DataTable `$('#user-notification-table_filter input').attr("placeholder", "Search for users");`